# how to add utf8 text to image with diffrent ttf fonts?

Tags: java, image, fonts

how do i add utf8 text to image with diffrent utf8 ttf fonts?(another language)

i have tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("E:/logo.png"));

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

   Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("E:/BYekan.ttf"));
    font.deriveFont(24F);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("some utf8 text", 20, 20);

    g.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("E:/image.png"));}
```

my problem is when i execute this code ,that result is instead clearly my text show just point into image how to fix this code?

my result is :
[my created image](http://codetowers.ir/image.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "utf8 text"? UTF-8 is just an encoding...

Answer (score 0):

did you use `canvases.drawText()`

update. 
you can add font to assets folder and set the typeface with it.